# How to use 2 fonts in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

How to use 2 fonts in WebStorm at once? Currently you can set the primary font and a secondary font, which is going to be used if primary is unavailable. Some themes, like this one: https://github.com/SintrumIT/oceanic-next-italic
are using 2 fonts.

One as the main and another as the italic for attributes.
If you want to simulate operator mono you can use one font as primary and another one as italic for attributes.

I'm using input mono, which doesn't fit to be the italic for the attributes. I need another font, but I can only use the primary font here. Is there a workaround or some setting to use several fonts while customizing the theme?

There is already an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161729) for that. So whoever need this exact feature - go vote for it!

Comment: I highly doubt this is possible. Why can't you just use one font?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson Because if I use input it will not look as nice as with the font that was intentionally designed to look nice as italic. Check out how the theme looks, it gives an idea of what my end goal is :-). Im asking it here as being able to do this will allow to use operator mono like font for free. And its between $200 and $600.

Comment: There is no such option -- only one font is used -- as in: you cannot specify what font to use for specific styling element (e.g. tag name will be using Font1 and tag attribute -- Font2). I believe I have seen similar request .. but cannot find it now (and don't remember what happened to that one). In any case -- feel free to submit new ticket -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: thanks for the info! Love the webstorm, so trying to customize it as much as I can. Good color theme is one of the things that make a huge difference for reading/writing the code. I`ll submit a ticker and update it here, for any one else that is trying to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

Not currently possible; please vote for [IDEA-161729](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161729) to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: Thank you for the update, Lena. I know its there when its done, but do you have an overage time that usually takes this kind of features to get into the next update of the webstorm? At least approximately, like 1 month, half a year, a year?

Comment: well, it depends... It may be a week or years. We normally take our customers’ feedback and votes into account  and discuss the feature implementation (requirements and timeline) right in the issue. Normally, the most popular requests are implemented. Of course, the time of delivery depends on the complexity and other plans that we have for the upcoming version, but we are pretty flexible. If you are talking about obligations or guarantees – we don’t provide any, concerning the feature requests, as it’s more like a custom development that we don’t really provide.